# memory request Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I have a c program that makes memory request. After that run my program i use the free -g -t command to see the memory used. The program call to the malloc function, but it does not  call the free function. For example:
 pointer=malloc(900000000*sizeof(double))
I thought that that  called would occupy ram memory but when i used the free command the free memory does not change . About 6 mega. I run the program a lot of times. The program don t free the memory but the free memory does not change.
i thouhgt that the operation free memory was in charge of the programmer in c.
My program is some more complicated than that, but the main operation is like that.

I don t underestand why the free (and occupped)   memory does not change.

Comment: Scribble on the allocated memory.  That should end up allocating it.  Linux assumes people will over-allocate and is lazy about committing the memory to your program.

Comment: I am not sure if i underestand your comment. You say that the output of the linux free command show me is not updated o something like that?

Comment: Probably.  I've not formally experimented but your symptoms match my suggested diagnosis.

Comment: malloc() does *not* allocate memory. It allocates **address space**. The memory will be *faulted in* once referenced.

Comment: FI,see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507066/905902

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan Leffler says in his comment, malloc() does not actually allocate the memory you ask for in *physical* memory, that happens first when you *use* the memory. If you write to the memory you got from malloc() then you will see that memory usage as seen by "free" will increase.

From [malloc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) under Notes:

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy.
>   This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee
>   that the memory really is available.

"free" reports the *physical* memory usage, as mentioned in [free man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/free)